# what is the best ubuntu tool for flow diagram and architectural diagram creation for journal papers with latex?

Tags: diagrams

I want to create high quality flow diagram, architectural diagram and mathematical diagram in Ubuntu for journal papers and I want to merge with LaTeX code also. The diagram could be converted to `.jpeg` format also. So kindly suggest some best software in Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look at Ti*k*Z: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf, http://www.texample.net/tikz/

Comment: As it stands this sounds like you are searching for a software recommendation, which would be off-topic for this forum.

Comment: I accept.. sorry.. If you don't mind can you guide me where can I ask this question?

Comment: If you want high quality, don't use `.jpeg` - better use some vector based format or as last resort `.png`

Comment: There is a software recommendation StackExchange site. Probably it is on-topic there.

Comment: Due to beginner of Latex, Initially I thought that drawings are drawn separately on different drawing software and merge it in latex through .jpg file. But, now I go through some examples in TikZ code I am comfortable with latex code itself to draw diagrams.. Thanks for your valuable suggestions..